# Coding arrow to accordion expand

Tags: html, css

I have looked at the other questions here but I'm not finding the answer I need.

My boss walked out, leaving me as pretty much the only person here, and I am stuck jumping into a responsive site design with only the most basic of html experience.  So I really need it spelled out for me step by step.

I would like to be able to add an arrow that is pointed right when an item is closed and down when it is opened.

I have my arrows created.  They are called right.png and down.png

**Please note:**  If you get through this and think there is an easier way for me to do this then I will simply get rid of his code and replace it with something you have that works.  I am so lost right now and my VP wants me to get this done.  Please help!

**How he set it up:**

This is the accordion code that the previous guy started to use.  It works but he didn't include the arrows in it.

script

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#gallery" ).accordion({
            heightStyle: 'content',
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false});
    });
```

/script

**This is the first element that expands.  Please note he has the first one defaulted to be open when a user comes to the page....**

div id="gallery"  (I had to remove the < > to make this show up it is at the top of the list of expanding parts)

```
            <h3 class="gallery">Associate of Arts in Liberal Arts</h3>
                <div class="photobox"><img class="image-left" src="images/aala.jpg" width="302" height="200" alt="" />
                    <p>Centenary's accelerated 64-credit hour AALA business program lets you complete your Associate of Arts degree in either in-class or online. This program focuses on business, leadership, teamwork, and communication. We provide students with the skills needed to start careers in a competitive and fast-moving economy. Our program focuses on leadership, teamwork, and communication. These skills build your personal growth, service to the community, and career advancement. Enhance your employment opportunities or transfer your credits to earn your Bachelor's degree. </p>
                </div>
```

**This is the second element that expands this one is defaulted to be closed when a user comes to the page.**

```
<h3 class="gallery">Bachelor of Science in Business Administration</h3> 
                <div class="photobox"><img class="image-left" src="images/bsba.jpg" width="302" height="200" alt="" />
                    <p>This accelerated 128-credit hour business program gives you the essentials in the business field. Your degree is organized into three parts: Core Requirements, the Business Major, and free electives. Core Requirements include courses from the liberal arts disciplines. This guarantees uniformity of study without sacrificing your educational interests.</p>
                </div>
```

I hope this is clear enough for everyone.

Thanks!

Edit:

Thanks for trying everyone.  I tried everything you guys suggested and I can't get it working. It's just too much for me to do.  Every time I add something or change something it breaks something else on the page.

I'll just tell them they will have to go without until they hire someone new.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Is each accordion part going to have it's own arrow to signify which section is open and which is closed?

Comment: I don't have time to type a full answer, but here's a way using pure CSS. If you need to use images instead of characters, use the background-image property on the span instead of the character on the ::next content. http://jsfiddle.net/thePivottt/574a2grb/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery UI accordion you just have to add the CSS that triggers the styling:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

EDIT: Used your code with the example jQuery UI accordion code, to get what you want:

Look at this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVpPmN

In the CSS section you see that I overwrite the standard CSS classes.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I don't know if jquery is being used or not, I've never worked in Jquery.  I'm so sorry, I feel so freaking stupid, I can't figure this out.  I looked at your example but I have no idea what to change or where to put any of the stuff you show.

Comment: If you look at your HTML file and you look what is inside:  '<head>' . Could you discover if there is a reference towards JQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

For jquery UI accordions, "icons" property can be given for active as well as inactive states. These can be customized to add  your own custom classes with your images as background.

```
var icons = {
  header: "",         //provideCustom Classes here for active and inactive states
  activeHeader: ""    //
};
$( "#gallery" ).accordion({
  icons: icons
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lcsbcn22/

Edit

Added a demo. Please look how the custom classes(red and blue) get placed at the accordion headers . Similarly you have to create two classes with your arrow images as background-image and put them in icons object.

Comment: What do I put where?  Do I put something between the "" after header?  what would I put there?